# How can I speed up filling this TListBox?

Tags: android, loops, delphi, listbox, firemonkey

### Problem

I have 2 different `json` `arrays` that looks like this:

**1 - Events List**

> {"0000:First Event Name","0001:Second Event Name","0002:Third Event Name"}

**2 - Available Events List**

> {"0001","0002"}

and then I need to generate a ListBox with the available events using checkboxes:

---

- [ ] First Event Name
- [x] Second Event Name
- [x] Third Event Name

---

### Given solution

```
procedure TFormHome.GetEvents(Sender: TObject);
var

    K: Integer;
    Z: Integer;
    ListCount_Events : Integer;
    AvailableList_Count : Integer;

    lb_item: TListBoxItem;

    event_code  : string;
    event_code_1: string;
    event_name  : string;

begin

    // Check if the JSON responses are not nil
    if ((json_response_events <> nil) and (json_response_available_events <> nil)) then
    begin

        ListCount_Events := json_response_events.Count;

        // Get Available List Count
        AvailableList_Count := json_response_available_events.Count;

        try
            // Run a for loop to create the events based on ListCount_Events
            for K := 0 to (ListCount_Events - 1) do
            begin

                // Get complete Event Code
                event_code_1 := StringReplace(json_response_events.Items[K].ToString.Split([':'])[0], '"', '', [rfReplaceAll]);

                // Get complete Event Name
                event_name := StringReplace(json_response_events.Items[K].ToString.Split([':'])[1], '"', '', [rfReplaceAll]);

                // Create the ListBoxItem
                lb_item := TListBoxItem.Create(self);

                // Assign it to the the ListBox component
                lb_item.Parent := lb_notifications;

                // ListBoxItem get the event name
                lb_item.Text := event_name;

                // Remove StyledSettings (Other)
                lb_item.StyledSettings := lb_item.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.Other];

                // Remove StyledSettings (FontColor)
                lb_item.StyledSettings := lb_item.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.FontColor];

                // Change TextSettings FontColor to default
                lb_item.TextSettings.FontColor := $FF626262;

                // Set selectable to false in order to not permit the user
                // to select multiple items on the List
                lb_item.Selectable := false;

                // Set the appropriated style
                lb_item.StyleLookup := 'listboxitemleftdetail';

                // Run a for loop to check the available events
                for Z := 0 to (AvailableList_Count) do
                begin

                        event_code := StringReplace(json_response_available_events.Items[Z].ToString, '"', '', [rfReplaceAll]);

                        if event_code_1.Contains(event_code) then
                        begin

                            if K < ListCount_Events then
                            begin

                                // Remove StyledSettings (FontColor)
                                lb_item.StyledSettings := lb_item.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.FontColor];

                                // Change TextSettings FontColor to available
                                lb_item.TextSettings.FontColor := $FF179ADF;

                                // Set the List CheckBox to checked
                                lb_item.IsChecked := true;
                            end;

                        end;
                end;

            end;

        finally
            begin
                // Call to List start at position 0
                lb_notifications.ItemIndex       := 0;
            end;
        end;

    end;
end;
```

---

I think my code smells and I want to know why and learn to do better.

Reasonable suggestions are welcome!

- It takes *too long* to load the list on both `Android` and `iOS`.
- When scrollable, it is incredibly slow on `Android` (but not on `iOS`).

### How can I accelerate filling up this list?

Comment: When adding many items use a beginupdate / endupdate on the listbox. Otherwise it will do a (slow) repaint on each new item.

Comment: `BeginUpdate/EndUpdate` was an excellent catch to load faster, however, it still slow to scroll on Android.

Comment: The FireMonkey TListBox is slow in scrolling due to its design of each TListBoxItem being a container of controls.  If you want faster performance when scrolling on mobile devices, take a look at the TListView or a 3rd party TListBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion by @birger, it was solved with 2 simple lines of code:

```
BeginUpdate;
//
GetEvents;
//
EndUpdate;
```

If you use a `Delphi` component like a `ListBox`, `Memo`, ListView,... and you add or modify a lot of items (lines, nodes,...), the component's performance becomes very slow. This is due to the fact that after each change, it is redrawn on the screen.

`BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` prevent excessive redraws and speed up processing time when items are added, deleted, or inserted.

Reference: http://www.festra.com/eng/tip-beginupdate.htm

Comment: in fact,by inserting the items(8000 in my case) beginupdate..endupdate does not help. The only change is; the form/component is shown very fast with some count of inserted items, but the insertion still goes on and u can see the list is growing. about the same effect as if u are using  "application.processmessages" but in this case u can close the form/applcation without waiting for completion of insertion(visually).